# How to start a bg thread on app startup in mvvm/wpf?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

What is the recommended way of starting a background thread on startup of wpf/mvvm app?  That is, I'd like to start a thread right after UI is initialized.  Ideally I'd like to use xaml/command to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: "Ideally I'd like to use xaml/command to achieve this". What stops you from doing so?

Comment: I simply do not know how to do it.  That is, I'm not sure where to put the markup code and what it should look like.  A suggestion or a sample would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nope.  Just put it in the constructor of app.xaml.cs.  Not everything belongs in markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through various articles on this site I realised that the way to go was to use EventTriggers.  In order to be able to incorporate the triggers into my app I had to download and install Expression Blend SDK.

Here is a sample code that works for me:

```
<Window x:Class="TestServer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"  
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <!-- Execute a method called 'StartDaemon' defined in the view model -->
            <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="StartDaemon"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
            <!-- Execute a method called 'StopDaemon' defined in the view model -->
            <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="StopDaemon"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Path=DaemonText}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do?  Are you sure you want a thread?
I assume your program is going to perform some resource intensive operation and you want the UI to stay responsive.
If you're using .NET 4.x, look into the Task Parallel Library.
If you're using .NET 5, look into the async/await pattern.

Here's what I've done in the past:
In the View:

```
<Button   ToolTip="Delete Selected Item" Command="{Binding DeleteItemCommand}"/>
```

In the ViewModel:

```
public DelegateCommand DeleteItemCommand { get; private set; }
```

(in the constructor of the ViewModel):

```
this.DeleteItemCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.DeleteItem, this.CanDeleteItem);

void DeleteItem()
{
    Task<int> task;
    try
    {
        task = Task.Run(() => YourTaskMethod(yourParameter));
        int result = task.Result;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
}
static int YourTaskMethod(YourParameterType yourParameter)
{
    //do complex stuff
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I do need a thread that will run during the app runtime.  It'll be responsible for querying database, checking file timestamps, querying remote servers using REST, etc.  and taking appropriate actions based on the result of queries.  Some of its status will be reported to the UI thread.  I could start the thread programmatically in app.xaml.cs but I wonder if there is a way to do it in the markup.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking a broad, high-level question.  I still don't think you want a 'thread' just hanging around, waiting to be used to do all the things you mentioned.  You're probably going to end up using a 'Task' to do these things as they are required.  A Task will hide the actual Thread management which can get tricky fast.   Hopefully this will help:  http://www.blfoley.com/2012/06/26/a-very-simple-introduction-to-the-task-parallel-library-tpl-in-c/

Comment: I think that we've side tracked a bit here. It could be that there might be [better] alternatives to a background thread.  However, regardless of what technique I use I will still need a way to initiate an action in a right place at a right time in a 'MVVM' way. Specifically, I need to trigger the action from XAML right after the UI is initialized.